# Increase column width of excel sheet using java code

Tags: java, excel, jxl

How to increase Column width of excel sheet using java code and jxl package?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Answer (score 0):

There is a method setColumnView(int col, int width) in WritableSheet.

See this reference:

http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/write/WritableSheet.html